# changing background color wont work on chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I have to zoom in and out in order to change the entire background color (but it works in IE wihtout any problem)!
P.S: Body bg color is gray by default.

link to code : http://jsfiddle.net/eY44d/

** THE BUTTONS CODE ARE AT THE END OF THE BODY **

** when i change the tab and go back to it it works fine too **

here is the code of the entire website

```
<body style="background-color:gray; ">
    <div style=" float:left;background-color:white; width:13%;height:100%; position:fixed; left:0; top:50px; border: 2px solid black;">
        <div id="menu" class="menu">    <a href="image.html">Shirts</a>
            <br/>----------------------
            <br/>   <a href="info.html">Shoes</a>
            <br/>----------------------
            <br/>   <a href="Text.html">Accessories</a>
            <br/>----------------------
            <br/>   <a href="Media.html">About Us</a> 
            <br/>----------------------
            <br/>   <a href="mailto:zaid-sh@live.com">Contact Us</a>
            <br/>----------------------
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="middle" style=" background-color:white; position:absolute; height:auto%; width:70%; left:15%; top:100px; ">
        <div style="position:relative;left:10px;top:10px;margin-right:5%; border: 3px solid #a3a3a3 ; border-spacing:10px;">
            <img src="shirt.jpg" alt="shirt" height="325px" width="412" />
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div style="position:relative;left:10px;top:10px;margin-right:5%; border: 3px solid #a3a3a3;">
            <img src="shoes.jpg" alt="shoes" height="325px" width="412" />
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div style="position:relative;left:10px;top:10px;margin-right:5%; border: 3px solid #a3a3a3;">
            <img src="watch.jpg" alt="watch" height="325px" width="412" ; "/>

        </div>
        <br/>       
    </div>

    <div  id="header-fixed " style="background-color:#4B4B4B; position:fixed; top:0;right:0; width:100%; height:50px; border: 2px solid black; ">
        <input class ="resize " id="pic " type="image " src="list.png "  onclick="show(); "/>

        <input class = "resizecol " type="image " src="blue.png " alt="white " value= "White " onclick="document.body.style.backgroundColor='blue' ; "/>
        <input class = "resizecol " type="image " src="black.png " alt="white " value= "White " onclick="document.body.style.backgroundColor='black' ; "/>
        <input class = "resizecol " type="image " src="white.png " alt="white " value= "White " onclick="document.body.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF' ; "/>

        <input id="Register " dir="ltr " style="position: fixed; right: 0px; top: -3px; height: 54px; width: 123px; " 
            type="image " value="Register " alt="Regsiter " src="register.png " />

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Does adding `!important` to  your JavaScript added styles make any difference? E.g. `document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue !important';`

Comment: Seems to work fine in Chrome. [**http://jsfiddle.net/jY2Hj/**](http://jsfiddle.net/jY2Hj/) clicking into the input boxes changes the color just fine. Your issue might be that some CSS in a file is over-writing the color changes. Hence why all CSS should stay in CSS files and be managed there so you can assign classes to do the work for you and let the CSS be manage independently. Also check if you have JavaScript disabled in Chrome by chance.

Comment: P.S.: You have a typo here: `<img src="watch.jpg" alt="watch" height="325px" width="412" ; "/>` It should be `<img src="watch.jpg" alt="watch" height="325px" width="412" />`

Comment: @BigChris when i add !important the button doesn't even work anymore.

Comment: OK, How about: `document.body.style.cssText = 'background-color:#ffffff !important';`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  body{background-color: #657383;}
```